# Having a repeating custom field in admin custom post type, what I'd go better with, for DB's sake? ACF repeater or query a different post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, database, advanced-custom-fields

I have:
A main custom post type - 'Cards' - each post showing its ACF repeater custom field - 'operations' - with the following sub-fields: 'add/remove', 'amount, 'value', 'date'.

Let's say the fully operational website will have 500 Cards posts, with about 50/100 operation rows each.

**What would be the less stressing solution, to keep querys and Database load reasonable?**

- Keeping my first choice and use custom fields with ACF repeater, inside the Cards posts.
- Creating a dedicated custom post type 'operations', one new post for every single repeated row, and query all the related 'operations' post from within the 'Card' post they belong to.

---

```
Card post & operation as ACF repeater fields:

    Card[post]
            operation [custom fields]
            operation [custom fields]
            operation [custom fields]
    ...
    Card
    Card
```

---

```
Card post & Operation as post:

    Card[post]
            {wp_query all the related operation[post], return operation[post] fields}
    ...
    Card
    Card

    Operation[post]
            [custom fields]
            [custom fields]
            [custom fields]
    ...
    Operation
    Operation
```

---

Any suggestion will be most appreciated.

Comment: Can Cards be a taxonomy?

Comment: @JacobPeattie sounds good and I didn't even thought about it as I started just considering Cards as the main item, so them being a post was sort of mandatory, but using taxonomies instead could be a native and elegant solution.
Thanks!